# Properly handling missing values and formatting for pandas data frame printed to tabulate

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, missing-data, tabulate

In the following scenario, I would like to:

- Replace the missing values with a custom character, for example `-`
- Apply custom formatting with respect to numbers

## Problem

I seem to be able to achieve only one of those goals. If I use the code below, I can achieve the desired results with respect to formatting; however the missing values are printed as `nan`

```
"""Handling Missing Data in Pandas / Tabulate
"""

import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# Create sample data
iris_data = sns.load_dataset('iris')
# Derive summary table
iris_summary = pd.DataFrame.describe(iris_data, percentiles=[]).transpose()
# Add missing values
iris_summary.iloc[0, 1:6] = None


# Show missing data
print(tabulate(iris_summary, missingval="-",
               floatfmt=(".0f", ".0f", ".3f", ".1f", ".4f", ".1f", ".0f")))
```

#### Results

```
------------  ---  -------  -----  --------  -----  ---
sepal_length  150  nan      nan    nan       nan    nan
sepal_width   150    3.057    0.4    2.0000    3.0    4
petal_length  150    3.758    1.8    1.0000    4.3    7
petal_width   150    1.199    0.8    0.1000    1.3    2
------------  ---  -------  -----  --------  -----  ---
```

### Attempt 1

I've tried replacing the missing values

```
iris_summary.replace(np.nan, "", inplace=True)
```

but the results are not satisfactory as the number formatting is lost:

```
------------  ---  ------------------  ------------------  ---  ----  ---
sepal_length  150
sepal_width   150  3.0573333333333337  0.4358662849366982  2.0  3.0   4.4
petal_length  150  3.7580000000000005  1.7652982332594662  1.0  4.35  6.9
petal_width   150  1.1993333333333336  0.7622376689603465  0.1  1.3   2.5
------------  ---  ------------------  ------------------  ---  ----  ---
```

## Desired results

I would like to arrive at the table that looks as fallows:

```
------------  ---  -------  -----  --------  -----  ---
sepal_length  150    -        -      -         -      -
sepal_width   150    3.057    0.4    2.0000    3.0    4
petal_length  150    3.758    1.8    1.0000    4.3    7
petal_width   150    1.199    0.8    0.1000    1.3    2
------------  ---  -------  -----  --------  -----  ---
```

---

## Notes

- The `tabulate` call is used within a function that outputs LaTeX tables. My intention is to see the solution flexible, so `tabulate` can received pandas [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) with missing values at different locations and correctly apply the formatting passed via the `floatfmt` to the remaining values within the column.

Comment: The desired result can be achieved using `df.fillna()` and `format = lambda x: '%.2f' % x` then doing `df.applymap(format)`. Is that what you are looking for?
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `replace`:

```
print(tabulate(iris_summary.replace(np.nan, None), missingval='-',
               floatfmt=(".0f", ".0f", ".3f", ".1f", ".4f", ".1f", ".0f")))
```

Output:

```
------------  ---  -----  ---  ------  ---  -
sepal_length  150  -      -    -       -    -
sepal_width   150  3.057  0.4  2.0000  3.0  4
petal_length  150  3.758  1.8  1.0000  4.3  7
petal_width   150  1.199  0.8  0.1000  1.3  2
------------  ---  -----  ---  ------  ---  -
```

I think `missingval` is for `None` value but Pandas convert `None` to `NaN` where the column has `float` dtype so you have to force to replace `nan` by `None` to get your expected output.

Comment: Thank you for the fix, I reported an issue at https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate/issues/316